# What is the difference between Scroll and Fling in android.widget.Scoller

Tags: android

While I'm reading the source code of [`android.widget.Scoller`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Scroller.java), I found the property `mMode` probably has 2 available value which are `SCROLL_MODE = 0;` and `FLING_MODE = 1;` What are the differences between scroll and fling gesture? Can anyone help explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Scrolling" is a word that can take on different meanings in Android,
>   depending on the context.
>
> **Scrolling** is the general process of moving the viewport (that is, the
>   'window' of content you're looking at). When scrolling is in both the
>   x and y axes, it's called panning. The sample application provided
>   with this class, InteractiveChart, illustrates two different types of
>   scrolling, dragging and flinging:
>
> **Dragging** is the type of scrolling that occurs when a user drags her finger across the touch screen. Simple dragging is often
>   implemented by overriding onScroll() in GestureDetector.OnGestureListener. For more discussion of dragging,
>   see Dragging and Scaling.
>
> **Flinging** is the type of scrolling that occurs when a user drags and lifts her finger quickly. After the user lifts her finger, you
>   generally want to keep scrolling (moving the viewport), but decelerate
>   until the viewport stops moving. Flinging can be implemented by
>   overriding onFling() in GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, and by
>   using a scroller object.